# Rearrange the order of programs in the Windows Open With... context menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, context-menu

I want to rearrange the order of programs in the Windows "Open with" context menu. For example VLC media player would be top of the list, instead of the 4th item in the list as it is in the below screenshot.

Is there a way to do it?

[image: Open With... context menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 different settings/locations for such a menu.

**Right Click Menu for Files** is under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\` (All the folders listed under ContextMenuHandlers are applications that show up when you right-click on a file in Windows.)

**Right Click Menu for Folders** is under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\` **and** `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell`

**Right Click Menu for Desktop** is under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell` **and** `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers`

A good way to clean and re-arrange a menu is to export the list, edit it from the exported file, then delete the reg entries and re-import the updated file.

This should be able to do it the easy - [File Menu Tools](https://www.lopesoft.com/index.php/en/download/filemenu-tools); overall many things matter, including alphabetical order (so you could use numbering also for sorting). Ultimate Windows Customizer, Right-Click Extender for Windows and Context Menu Editor for Windows are other freeware tools supporting this.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really highly appreciate that. Now I see program names that I want to rearrange. If I would like to rearrange VLC, what am I to do for it, please?

Comment: I've added some tools that can alter this to the answer; it's easier using them then manually re-making the menu from registry.

Comment: Wow, you gave quick answer, appreciate that. I just need to learn manually re-making method, because I need only 2 apps to be at the top of the open with list context menu.

Comment: In that case, export the others (you don't want at top), delete them from registry and re-import them. Or export all and re-import using numbering (like 1-App1, 2-App2, etc) so they auto-sort like that.

Comment: OK, I will try them. And I will back here.